# Wordpress local website login page refreshing and wont let me log in

Tags: wordpress, https, localhost

I am making a wordpress website locally on my computer, and I accidentally changed the URL to https. That crashed the website since I didn't have an SSL certificate, but I managed to change the URL back to http. However, now I am unable to log in to my local website and the login page just keeps refreshing. When I put in http://localhost/mysite it just shows a blank page and a message next to the URL saying my https is not secure.

I tried changing the URL through the wp-config file with
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/mysite');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/mysite');
expecting it to let me log in to the wp-admin page, but it didn't change anything.

Update-
I have also tried renaming my plugin file - which got rid of the "white screen of death". But I still cannot log in to wp-admin. I deleted the .htaccess file as well but it made no difference.

Comment: try logout first `http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout` or try another browser